# How can I let the user choose a currency to use in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, currency, preference

I have an app in which I let the user add products and set a price for them. Now I want to let the user choose the currency for these prices. How do I do that? I mean, should I make a custom list of all currencies, then associate these with a proper locale, which I then can send to `NSNumberFormatter`, or is there some better way?

Comment: Do you really need a currency? Do you plan on doing price conversions between currencies? Usually a notice that says all prices are in US dollars, or Pounds, or whatever is appropriate.

Comment: @AaronBratcher The mentioned app is mainly hypothetical. I cannot tell you the real context due to secrecy. All I can tell you is that you set a currency for display purposes only. There will never be any occasions where currency is to be converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to display to users, creating your own configuration could be best. You can also query `NSLocale` to get the `availableLocaleIdentifiers` which you could display (or use to filter your custom list to locales the system understands). Setting the locale of the number formatted is much better and more reliable than trying to specify your own formats.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the acailableLocaleIdentifiers! I was actually looking for an answer on how to get that list, but I forgot to mention it. Thanks for reading my thoughts!